# How to get variable as a result of a comparison?

Tags: c#, if-statement, properties, comparison, max

I have a windows form and a simple horce racing application. My horses are pictureBox controls. I want to print the winner by checking who is more far away from starting point.

```
    control aa.left = (unknown integer value);
    control bb.left = (unknown integer value);
    control cc.left = (unknown integer value);
```

- If first one has the biggest value, I want to print "First one is champion"
- If second one has the biggest value, I want to print"Second one is champion"
- If third one has the biggest value, I want to print "Third one is champion"

Is there an easy way to do this other then creating an if structure - "check aa with bb, aa with cc, bb with cc"

In other words, how to get the variable with biggest left property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just do this:

pseudocode:

```
let biggest = aa
if (bb.left > biggest.left)
    biggest = bb
if (cc.left > biggest.left)
    biggest = cc

print(biggest.name + " is the champion)
```

If you have a lot more, then u can use an array

ie.

```
arrayOfBoxes = [aa, bb, cc]
let biggest = arrayOfBoxes[0]
for each box in arrayOfBoxes
    if (box.left > biggest.left)
        biggest = box
print(biggest.name + " is the champion)
```

Comment: thank you, that is an algorithmic way of doing it. It did not come to my mind.

Comment: Since you only have 3 elements, the algorithmic way doesn't provide much benefits over doing the 3 if statements, but for N elements, the runtime difference will be O(N) vs O(N^2) (difference between linear and polynomial time)

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could do it is grab the controls that you care about into a list:

```
var horses = Controls.Cast<Control>()
    .Where(c => c.Name == "aa" || c.Name == "bb" || c.Name == "cc");
```

If you have a lot of controls that represent horses, it might be easier to give them all some common `Tag` value, so you can search on just that field:

```
var horses = Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(c => c.Tag.ToString() == "horse");
```

Then you can find the winning horse by getting the `Name` of the control (or the `Text`, or whichever property you store the identifier that the user would understand) whose `Left` property is the `Max`:

```
var winner = horses.First(l => l.Left == horses.Max(h => h.Left)).Name;
MessageBox.Show($"The winner is: {winner}!");
```